# Android app that can move an email, with a single click, from the inbox to a specific folder on the email provider's server?

Tags: android, email, email-client

I'm looking for an Android app I can use to read my email (Hotmail / Outlook mail) and, while viewing an email, click on a button (single click) to move it to a specific, pre-defined folder on the email server.

Outlook 2016 on the PC has this feature in the form of Quick Actions.

I'd just like to be able to quickly move a mail to one of a few folders, and automatically view the next one.

Comment: Not tried, but according to [this list](https://bestforandroid.com/email-apps/) there's [Nine Mail](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ninefolders.hd3) should be capable of that (swipe left/right for "quick actions like … moving a message").

Comment: Thanks Izzy I've emailed them to check - I want to do the whole thing with one gesture/click, not have to select the folder etc.

Comment: I've tried out Nine Mail - it doesnt appear to do this from the mail full view screen

Comment: No idea then, sorry.